# Problem taking program pauses in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, proc

I'm making a Tetris game. I am doing a proc to perform arrow recognition to perform the move, if no key is pressed then the piece continues to descend. My goal is for the tetris piece to fall every 1 second. For this I did this proc:

```
TECLADO proc
     ino: 
     mov ah,01h
     int 16h
    jz semtec
    mov ah,00h
    int 16h

    call COMPTEC
    jmp TECLADO
   semtec:
    mov     ah, 00h
    int     1ah
    cmp     dx, wait_time
    jb      ino
    add     dx, 4
    mov     wait_time, dx 

ret
endp
```

;  wait_time dw    0

In the semtec part you should take a 1 second break to continue ... but the piece keeps going down very fast. Could anyone tell me why int 1ah is not working?

Comment: The clock counts at 18.2 counts per second, so 4 counts is about 220 ms.

Comment: Is TECLADO ever supposed to return? The ret instruction is unreachable.

Comment: Hello @prl , how are you? Tried for add dx, 4 and it didn't work. The old proc looked something like this: In the old proc there was nothing in semtec, that led straight to ret. And the jmp Keyboard had below the COMPTEC that compares the keys.

Comment: I would need to add the 1 second timer to each drop of the piece, but I can't, could you help me?

Comment: I tried to put the keyboard jmp where it was, below COMPTEC, but again it had no results.